# select the next order of data in tableB using current data in tableA

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables: tableA and tableB

**tableA**

```
------------------------------
|      CD      |   stg_cd    |
------------------------------
|    APDN_82   |   CUSC      |
|    APDN_82   |   CUC       |
------------------------------
```

**tableB**

```
------------------------------
|     stg_cd   |   srt_ordr  |
------------------------------
|    CUSC      |     1       |
|    KLD       |     3       |
|    CUC       |     2       |
------------------------------
```

I am trying to select the next order of data(i.e CUC) in tableB using current data(i.e CUSC) in tableA

My Expected result should be like

```
------------------------------
|     CD       |   stg_cd    |
------------------------------
|    APDN_82   |     CUC     |
------------------------------
```

This is what i tried

```
 (SELECT * FROM tableA AS A
            WHERE A.ID = 'APDN_82' AND A.stg_cd 
        IN (SELECT lead('CUSC') over (order by B.srt_ordr) from tableB AS B)
```

But here i got a error : 'lead' is not a recognized built-in function name.
I tried to change the compatibility level to 110, but i did not had permission to change it.
Is there any other way to do without using lead ?

Comment: is srt_ordr autoincremnted by 1??

Comment: What version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: @Salman : I use version 2008

Comment: @nikhilsugandh : No, its not autoincremented. But your answer is write.

Comment: @Karthik then give it a green tick haha thanks!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Would write it this way:

```
SELECT * 
      FROM TABLEA AS A
     WHERE A.ID = 'APDN_82' 
       AND A.STG_CD IN (SELECT STG_CD 
                          FROM TABLEB 
                         WHERE SRT_ORDR IN (SELECT B.SRT_ORDR + 1 
                                              FROM TABLEB AS B 
                                             WHERE B.STG_CD = 'CUSC'
                                            )
                        )
```

Answer (score 1):

this will work:

```
select n.* from tableA n,(select * from tableB  where srt_ordr=(select srt_ordr from 
tableB where stg_cd='CUSC')+1)m  
where 
n.stg_cd=m.stg_cd
```

Comment: This answer is also working, but you did not check the other condition which is ID ='APDN_82'. Thank you

Comment: @Karthik i did n.* there it will come ID ='APDN_82' what to chekc for  it??

Comment: Yes Nikhil, you are right. i am sorry that i did not included other entries in my table, but it contains different data in each rows. like 'APDN_83' may also contains 'CUSC' and 'CUC'. Due to mess up, i did not included.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to partition by `tablea.CD` and find next row per partition. You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT tablea.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tablea.CD ORDER BY tableb.srt_ordr) AS rn
    FROM tablea
    INNER JOIN tableb ON tablea.stg_cd = tableb.stg_cd
    WHERE tableb.srt_ordr > (SELECT srt_ordr FROM tableb WHERE stg_cd = 'CUSC')
)
AS x
WHERE rn = 1
```

[Demo on DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=85217fbca1bab20209b42d1185352c55)

Or you could use correlated sub query:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablea
WHERE stg_cd = (
    SELECT TOP 1 stg_cd
    FROM tableb
    WHERE stg_cd IN (
        SELECT stg_cd
        FROM tablea AS x
        WHERE x.CD = tablea.CD
    )
    AND srt_ordr > (
        SELECT srt_ordr
        FROM tableb
        WHERE stg_cd = 'CUSC'
    )
)
```

[Demo on DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=89b7e91a1377fc521151cbda0bb37495)

Comment: I have many rows. I tried your query, It gives many data rows in a result set. and the result set does not contains my desired result.

Comment: Do you want exactly next row (CUC only) or all rows after it (CUC and KLD)?

Comment: Exactly the next row based on the sort order. i.e CUC only

Comment: See revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like

```
SELECT CD,
       stg_cd2
FROM
    T1 JOIN
    (
      SELECT TB1.stg_cd stg_cd1,
             TB1.srt_ordr srt_ordr1,
             TB2.stg_cd stg_cd2,
             TB2.srt_ordr srt_ordr2
      FROM T2 TB1 JOIN T2 TB2
      ON TB1.srt_ordr + 1 = TB2.srt_ordr
    ) TT
ON T1.stg_cd = TT.stg_cd1
WHERE T1.stg_cd = 'CUSC'
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=43b94a66eaf0997ca434c4b7886b450b)**

Comment: Thank you for your effort and time for doing the fiddle . Your answer too helped me.